# How do I fix this error I get when I try to load pages on my Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, development-environment

I am developing my wordpress site. I have access all of the dashboard/admin areas and I can load the homepage. But when I attempt to view any of the pages or posts I have written, I get this error:

*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

Can you help me correct this issue so that those pages are visible?
Thanks!

Comment: You likely have an error in your PHP code which is causing a syntax error and stopping your page to load, you need to be able to see the server logs to debug further.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Like @tristansokol said this is probably an error in the PHP code somewhere and server logs would be the best place to start looking to track the problem down. Additionally have a look at this link to [creating a minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question. Updating the question with more information is likely to result in better answers. In it's current state only guesses can be made as to the cause of the error 500.

Answer (score 0):

I would try disabling plugins. Most often this caused by a bad plugin or a conflict between two plugins. You can check your server error log or can add the following code to your wp-config.php file to see the error

define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the following will fix the problem:

- Go to Settings -> Permalinks (on wp-admin dashboard menu)
- Select Plain (under Common Settings)
- Save Changes

... and check. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are using Dreamhost. They use Apache's mod_security and have a strict security ruleset. You may have locked yourself out due to repeated failed login attempts or other "suspicious" activities.

You just have to turn off mod_security for a while, and after a couple of hours re-enable it.

If you use Dreamhost, you can do this on their Hosting Panel. Other hosting services may have similar options, and if you "rolled your own" Apache with mod_security, check the documentation on how to disable it temporasrily. 
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215947927-How-do-I-enable-Extra-Web-Security-for-my-website-

Be aware that, in disabling mod_security, you may be putting your site at risk, and that maybe it was not yourself who tried the failed attempts...

Comment: What I mean is, it's not on Weordpress itself, but on Apache.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed and image should be added as image , not as a link.